# While("abc"); causes an error in java and it does not cause any error in c . Why?

Tags: java, c, while-loop, boolean

I tried the below code in both java and c++ , but it throwed an error in java while it does not throw an error in c++. Why is it so ?

```
while("abc"){ }
```

I do know it purely depends on the property of languages. But I would like to know why java set a condition that only boolean values should be allowed in loops ?

Comment: why do you want to compare Java and C? They are completely different languages. "abc" in Java is a String, and can NOT be used as a conditional expression, which is what you need. 'while ( EXPRESSION IS TRUE) {} '

Comment: Because Java and C are different languages?

Comment: Both compilers are developed with their own way

Comment: There shouldn't be any doubts as to why a non-Boolean expression is disallowed in Boolean context in Java, right? The only question should be "why the heck is it allowed in C" :-) The answer is "because it is allowed in assembly language".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, because of legacy stuff and because C was favoured by most programmers in the 80-90ies over the Pascal-Languages. Most assembly languages have no idea about "boolean" or non-boolean and when it comes to conditions, most CPUs use status-flags which have no actual counterpart in C.

Comment: **It is because it is!** Why is the sky blue? Why did the chicken cross the road? Why ask "why?"? Anybody can ask a "why?" question... but can you understand *when it's the most suitable tool for the job?* That's a question for you to think about...

Comment: In C `while()` (as well as `if` or its ternary operator) simply does not expect a boolean value but a scalar (expression), that's all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it shows lack of fundamental knowledge of programming languages

Comment: @user902383 Probably better with "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are talking about compiler error and not run-time

in case of java

```
while ( expression ) { 
// expression must evaluate to boolean value true or false
// as far as I knwo "abc" is neither true or false when it comes to java hence error
}
```

in C

```
while ( expression ) {
 // expression can be anything which finally gives a value of either 0 or a number 
// "abc" in this case will evaluate to an address which is positive integer hence no error
}
```

Comment: I want to know why is it different ? Is there any advantage in doing so ?

Comment: it is different, because the creators of the languages chose to implement it differently.

Comment: any advantage in doing so ?

Comment: @ShijoJoseph Yes , infinite loop .

Comment: In C "*expression*" is expected to be of a scalar type, which pointers are. As already mentioned in the answer, if an array is used here it decays to a pointer of its 1st element.

Comment: @ShijoJoseph: There is no advantage when using a literal, but using a pointer to a `char` (which could be treated like a "string") gives a lot of flexibility in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the same reason that `while(1)` is allowed in C but not in Java. Both of the languages evaluate expressions differently.

In case of C, there was originally no boolean type (it was introduced in C99), and any integer that is 0 was decided to be 'false', otherwise to be considered 'true'. In expression:

```
while("abc")
```

It resolves to the address which is positive integer so it works.

In case of Java, expressions must evaluate to true or false value. String "abc" does not evaluate to a boolean value so an error is observed.

Comment: There are some problems with this answer: 1. If C has no 'boolean' type, explain `<stdbool.h>`... 2. If an address is a positive integer, then why can't we multiply addresses by other integers, or assign them to `float`s?

Comment: 1. In C99, boolean type was introduced which was not existing in C89/90.

Comment: So part of this answer has an element of history... You could say "In the case of C, there was originally no boolean type. The integer value 0 was decided to be one of a few false values."

Comment: Then perhaps mention that `NULL` (and other null pointer constants) are required to compare unequal to any objects (e.g. arrays generated from string literals), and that they are the only pointers that can compare equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Because in java `The while statement evaluates expression, which must return a boolean value.`
You can read about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

C allows you to type anything you want in a condition of while loop.

If you dissasemble C while( something ), you will see, that the value in the parentheses is loaded in the `eax` register (in your case, value in the parentheses is the address of "abc"), then `eax` checks for `zero` and, if it is zero, loop ends. Like this:

```
mov eax, <"abc" offset>
test eax, eax
je <"after loop" offset>
jmp <loop offset>
```

P.S.:
Because "abc" offset is a non-zero value, your loop will never end.

Comment: "C allows you to type anything you want in a condition of while loop." ... so I should be allowed to write `while (poverty and hunger exist in third world countries)` or `while (/* this does nothing */)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Note that C is the oddball in this case, not Java.  Most of C's contemporaries (Fortran, Pascal, old-school BASIC, etc.) behave like Java, where the condition must be a Boolean value (or a Boolean-valued expression).  C didn't acquire a true Boolean datatype until the 1999 revision, long after a whole generation of C programmers (myself included) grew accustomed to writing code without it.

In C, any non-zero integral value is considered `true` in a Boolean context.  It's a common idiom to check that a pointer value isn't `NULL` as follows:

```
FILE *in = fopen( filename, "r" );
if ( in ) 
{
  // in is not NULL, fopen was successful
}
```

As long as the pointer value `in` is not `NULL`, the condition evaluates to `true`.  The risk with this approach is that non-`NULL` pointer values aren't necessarily *valid* pointer values.  It will be in this case (`fopen` will return either a valid pointer value or `NULL`), but code like the following:

```
void foo ( void )
{
  int *p;
  ...   
  if ( p ) { ... }
  ...
}
```

is risky; if `p` is never initialized or assigned to, then it will contain an *indeterminate* value which will most likely be neither a valid pointer nor `NULL`.

In most other languages, the same condition would be written as the equivalent of

```
if ( in != NULL )
```

which is a Boolean-valued expression that can *only* yield the values `true` and `false`.

Since `"abc`" evaluates to a non-zero pointer value, it can be used in a similar context (although it's not very useful, since the address will never change).